# Where to put methods (non get and set) in java project to be Spring MVC compliant

Tags: java, spring, class, model-view-controller, methods

working on a java Spring project, my group is conflicting between Delphi and Java approach I believe regarding methods location. (Read: http://www.gbengasesan.com/fyp/5/ch5.htm#Classes -> where I see Delphi seems to regroup methods in one class).

For instance, we have some classes including User, Invoice, Debt, etc.
So as a User has a List of Invoices, how is this correct to put all methods (except getter and setter) regarding a single Invoice in the User class ?!

I can't figure out. In my opinion, methods such as "create invoice" (that would execute the constructor at least, because some 'set methods' would complete the object afterwards), "modify invoice" or "delete invoice" should belong to Invoice class. 
Just the same idea for methods around User creation, modification, deletion or password recovery (could be simple get method that one) would then belong to User class and so on for the rest of the app.

Also should we only have getters and setters (besides constructors) as long as we didn't get into the full Spring model. I hope i was clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spring mvc we use service/business layer for those. User, invoice and debt has its own POJOs which will only have simple definition of data.

If you want to find all invocies belongs to one user. Or debts belong to one user those goes to debts service layer or POJOs which has getDebts. or Service layer which has function like getDebst(long user Id) which will bring user related data.

you can see more details in https://medium.com/stackavenue/why-to-use-service-layer-in-spring-mvc-5f4fc52643c0 or https://www.baeldung.com/testing-the-java-service-layer

Comment: thanks for the explanation and links on service layer. Though i'm reading it later